# Overhead for mlockall in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

Is there any difference between setting mlockall on for elasticsearch nodes or disabling swap at the OS level? I was reading the readme of the mlockall java agent, which is what I think elastic search uses for its mlockall option (at https://github.com/LucidWorks/mlockall-agent) and the author writes:

#### Is this agent a good substitute for running with swap disabled?

No, mlockall-agent.jar is not a good substitute for running with swap disabled.
If you have the resources to run your important java processes on dedicated
hardware with swap disabled that is recommended instead of using this agent --
but not everyone has that luxury, and this agent is for you.

But doesn't elaborate as to why.